# Como guardar un array dentro de otro array y luego guardar en Firebase

Tags: javascript, array, firebase, object

Help!
tengo este fragmento de código para almacenar lo siguiente:

```js
    var company = {
      description: "",
      logoPath: "",
      logoUrl: ""
    };
    var companiesArray = {
      length: 0,
      addElem: function addElem(elem) {
        [].push.call(this, elem);
      }
    };
    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      company.description = "descripcion";
      company.logoPath = "/urlpath/img.png";
      company.logoUrl = "http://domain.com";
      companiesArray.addElem(company)
    }
    // Luego, tengo que recuperar companiesArray.company para registrarlo en la base de datos Firebase.
    console.log(companiesArray.company); //undefinied
```

¿Cual sería el problema?

Answer (score 0):

He cambiado tu propuesta un poco y lo he dejado asi, a ver si cumple tus requisitos.

```js
var company = {
 description: '',
 logoPath: '',
 logoUrl: ''
};

// companiesArray ahor tienen un array de items, en este caso de companies
var companiesArray = {
 length: 0,
 items: []
};

for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
 company.description = 'descripcion';
 company.logoPath = '/urlpath/img.png';
 company.logoUrl = 'http://domain.com';
  companiesArray.length++;
 companiesArray.items.push(company)
}

// El primero
console.log(companiesArray.items[0]);
```